styling dynamically produced columns of a wpf datagrid using values from the first column
I have this data grid I am generating the columns dynamically other than the first column using the following code.
var viewModel = (SnapshotViewModel)DataContext;
foreach (var date in OverviewCompViewModel.DateColumns)
{
    
    var column = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = date,
        Binding = new Binding($"DateValues[{date}]"),
    };
    HistoricDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}

Its financial data is reflective of a typical financial statement Metric Yearx, yeary, yearz, etc.
MY question is how can I format the rows based on the value for that given row in the metric tab. For example I would like to make it so that if the metric contains growth then its a percentage and if the value is > 0 then the colour is green and < 0 red etc is this even possible?
This is my xaml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="HistoricDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding FinancialMetrics}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
 
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Metric" Binding="{Binding Metric}" />            
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>



If you could give maybe a screenshot of a hardcoded example, it might help flesh out the idea. and maybe a code example of the datagrid with hardcoded styling of a full row.
it seems like what you need is maybe a DataTemplateSelector, or maybe a DataTrigger, but I would need an example of the expected outcome to really try to help.

have a look at IValueConverter. Since your data is bound, provide parameter to IValueConverter. you could also use Trigger styling.

Ive added a picture of what I want specifically I have changed the code to make a stack panel and then edited the individual text blocks which seems very hacky but i wanted to get something done as a place holder in the mean time @GingerNinja

Your specification is for dynamic columns, which makes things more interesting. One way to meet your spec is by using DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn. That's the short answer (the rest is details).
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    .
    .
    .
    // Subscribe to static event
    FinancialMetric.DynamicValueCollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(DataContextProperty, new Binding($"[{e.Key}]"));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Text"));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new Binding("ForeColor"));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, new Binding("BackColor"));
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0));

        var template = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = textBlockFactory,
        };

        HistoricDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            Header = e.Key,
            CellTemplate = template
        });
    }
    .
    .
    .
}


It takes a few steps to glue the bindings together, and before I waste your time reading below where I explain things, you might want to clone and run my working example to verify that this is the kind of behavior you're looking for.

Example FinancialMetric class (represents a line item bound to a grid row)
What the above snippet says about the FinancialMetric object that's bound to a given row is that there needs to be an indexer that provides the data context for the individual formatted cell. There's going to be a key (the dynamically specified column name) and the indexer needs to return "some object" that can provide the ForeColor, BackColor, and (formatted) Text.
As a forward reference, we'll be making our own FormattableObject class that can wrap any object while also providing the cell-specific format info. We know that FinancialMetric class must provide an indexer for FinancialMetric that can set or get one of these objects, and subscribing to an event that will give FinancialMetric the "final say" on the formatting of a given cell value, based on runtime calculations by the containing object.
class FinancialMetric
{
    // The indexer for new Binding($"[{e.Key}]")
    public FormattableObject? this[string key]
    {
        get => _columns.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : null;
        set
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                if (_columns.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _columns.Remove(key);
                    ColumnChanged?.Invoke(this, new ColumnChangeEventArgs(key));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _columns[key] = value;                

                // This is the DYNAMIC GLUE that allows this specific
                // FinancialMetric to respond to this specific FormattableObject.
                value.PropertyRequestedFromParent -= ProvidePropertyValue;
                value.PropertyRequestedFromParent += ProvidePropertyValue;

                // This is an event, declared static, that informs the grid that
                // this value goes in a column named {key} which needs to be created
                // if it doesn't already exist.
                DynamicValueCollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new DynamicValueChangedEventArgs(key, value));
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(key);
        }
    }
    private readonly Dictionary<string, FormattableObject> _columns = new();
    .
    .
    .
    public static event EventHandler<DynamicValueChangedEventArgs>? DynamicValueCollectionChanged;
}


USAGE: Create 5 different line items with dynamic column values.
// Add line items with initial formatting, but Parent gets the final word.
DataContext.FinancialMetrics.Add(new FinancialMetric(Metric.Growth)
{
    {"2022", "-4.0%" }, // Using implicit string CTOR
    {"2023", " 1.2%" },
    {"2024", "11.9%" },
});
DataContext.FinancialMetrics.Add(new FinancialMetric(Metric.EBIT));
DataContext.FinancialMetrics.Add(new FinancialMetric(Metric.ROI));
DataContext.FinancialMetrics.Add(new FinancialMetric(Metric.Revenue)
{
    {"2023", new FormattableObject{Target= 999999.00, ForeColor = Brushes.Blue } },
});
DataContext.FinancialMetrics.Add(new FinancialMetric(Metric.StockPrice)
{
    {"2023", new FormattableObject{Target= 66.22, ForeColor = Brushes.Maroon } },
    {"2024", new FormattableObject{Target= 11.8, ForeColor = Brushes.Red } },
});



FinancialMetric gets the final say on formatting.
If we have a FinancialMetric instance, we could use the expression var formattedObject = lineItem["2023"]. This is exactly what the DataGridTemplateColumn binding is doing. And since the grid is going to come get the value to paint the cell using this FormattableObject, the trick is going to be eventing the line item first.
class FormattableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object? Target
    {
        get => _target;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_target, value))
            {
                _target = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    object? _target = default;

    private T? RequestFromParent<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        var e = new RequestFromParentEventArgs<T>(propertyName ?? string.Empty);
        PropertyRequestedFromParent?.Invoke(this, e);
        return e.NewValue ?? value;
    }

    // Requesting the formatted value of ForeColor from parent.
    public Brush? ForeColor
    {
        get => RequestFromParent(_foreColor);
        set
        {
            if (_foreColor != value)
            {
                _foreColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    // Requesting the formatted value of the Text from parent.
    public string? Text => RequestFromParent(Target?.ToString());

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyRequestedFromParent;
    .
    .
    .
    // Implicit conversions
    public static implicit operator FormattableObject(double value) =>
        new FormattableObject { Target = value };

    public static implicit operator FormattableObject(string value) =>
        new FormattableObject { Target = value };
}


Example of Parent handling the formatting request
class FinancialMetric : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, FormattableObject>>
{
    .
    .
    .
    private void ProvidePropertyValue(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic generic = e;
        if (sender is FormattableObject formattable)
        {
            var formatTarget = formattable.Target as IFormattable;
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(FormattableObject.Text):
                    // T E X T    S A M P L E S
                    switch (Metric)
                    {
                        case Metric.Revenue:
                            if (formatTarget is null)
                            {
                                generic.NewValue = formattable.Target?.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                generic.NewValue = formatTarget.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Metric.StockPrice:
                            if (formatTarget is null)
                            {
                                generic.NewValue = formattable.Target?.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                generic.NewValue = formatTarget.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case nameof(FormattableObject.ForeColor):
                    // C O L O R    S A M P L E S
                    switch (Metric)
                    {
                        case Metric.Growth:
                            generic.NewValue = $"{formattable.Target}".Contains("-") ?
                                Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case nameof(FormattableObject.BackColor):
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

